# how to implement negative binomial Regression for count models in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

i have implemented it in R using glm.nb() and also implemented in python using stats models api. but couldn't find the appropriate one in pyspark.

```
library(MASS)                # r-code
freg <- formula(ClaimNb ~ DriverAge + CarAge + Density + Brand + Power + Gas + offset(log(Exposure)))
regnb2 <- glm.nb(freg,data = CONTRACTS.f)
summary(regnb2)

from statsmodels.formula.api import glm     # python-code
regnb2 = glm(formula = form, data = contracts ,family = sm.families.NegativeBinomial(alpha=1)).fit()
print(regnb2.summary())
```

required the pyspark version.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.